# Help evaluating this complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Compute the integral $$\int_{\gamma} (\overline{z})^2 dz$$ where $\gamma$ is the contour $y=x^2 +1$ with initial point $z=0$ and terminal point $z=1+2i$
where $\overline{z}$ is the conjugate of $z$

I think i might just be having trouble finding a good parameterization. Any hints or tips?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Let $z(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$, $y(t)=t^2+1$, and $x(t)=t$ with $t\in[0,1]$ then
$dz(t)=(x'(t)+iy'(t))dt$ and
$$\int_{\gamma} (\overline{z})^2 dz=\int_{0}^1(x(t)-iy(t))^2(x'(t)+iy'(t))dt=\int_{0}^1(t-i(t^2+1))^2(1+i2t)dt.$$
Now expand the integrand function and then evaluate the integral of the real part and the integral of the imaginary part.

Comment: This doesn't have an initial point at $z=0$ though, does it?

Comment: You are right, but $z=0$ or $(0,0)$ is not on the contour $y=x^2+1$. That's strange . Could you please check your statement?